# Setting a new variable from a JSON variable React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, jsx

I am making a react football app. One of my components should show more details about a fixture when selected from a list of fixtures. I am setting the fixture by importing the ID from a click and then filter my list of fixtures (which I get from an API) to this ID. I then want to set the variables for the team names, stadium, date etc. so that I can render these in my app.

My code for this is as follows

```
const gameID = useLocation()
let fixture = worldcupFixtures.filter(fixtures => fixtures._id == gameID.state._id)
let home = fixture[0].teams.home.name
let away = fixture[0].teams.away.name
let homeLogo = fixture[0].teams.home.logo
let awayLogo = fixture[0].teams.away.logo
let date = fixture[0].fixture.date.substring(0, 10)
let time = fixture[0].fixture.date.substring(11, 16)
let stadium = fixture[0].fixture.venue.name
```

and my fixture variable works as I can print this on the front end, and the json looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uE36r.jpg). However, none of my other variables work when I try to render them, although my app compiles I do not see anything and the console gives me this error -> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'home')

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Given the code shown, the error means that `fixture[0].teams` is `undefined`.  When you `console.log(fixture[0])` (or otherwise debug when the error occurs) what does it output to the console?

Comment: It is defined, on console.log(fixture) I get the JSON I would expect for the fixture

Comment: That's all well and good, but asserting that isn't going to convince the error message to change its mind.  If the error is occurring in the code shown then it means that `fixture[0].teams` is `undefined`.  Your next step is to debug the code.  Is the code being invoked multiple times?  Is there a different value of `fixture` between those times?  Your debugging task is to determine what is the exact observed runtime value of `fixture[0]` (or `fixture`) *when the error occurs*.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the data in the `fixture` array? The `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'home')` error means the `teams` property of the first entry in `fixture` is `null`/`undefined`. Assuming `worldcupFixtures` is your data source in this case, might want to verify your `filter()` has valid values before attempting to read properties of data in the array it returns.

Comment: yes I have, the fixture variable filters correctly as can be seen in the screenshot of the json I attached